# Gulp uglify unable to handle arrow functions

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-uglify

I'm trying to compress my project using `gulp-uglify`, however gulp seems to throw the error `Unexpected token: punc ()` whenever it encounters an arrow function in the code. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thank you.

#### gulp-crash-test.js

```
// Function with callback to simulate the real code
function test(callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") callback();
}

// Causes a crash
test(() => {
    console.log("Test ran successfully!");
});

// Doesn't cause a crash
test(function () {
    console.log("Test ran successfully!");
});
```

#### gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

gulp.task("scripts", function() {
    gulp.src([
        "./gulp-crash-test.js"
    ]).pipe(
        concat("gulp-crash-test.min.js")
    ).pipe(
        uglify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
        })
    ).pipe(
        gulp.dest("./")
    );
});

gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch("./gulp-crash-test.js", ["scripts"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["watch", "scripts"]);
```

Comment: You could practice with arrow functions in your gulpfile.js. But first check your node.js version.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Arrow functions are an ES6 feature. Babel (and others) are designed to translate ES6 to ES5 or earlier as part of your build process. Luckily there are Babel plug-ins for Gulp and Grunt. Run Babel before uglify.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel

I hope this steers you in the right direction/somebody can demonstrate some code.

Comment: @Rein You could also use the harmony branch of uglify.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js-harmony

Comment: Appears latest module is gulp-ugligy-es which will handle ES6. Other modules mentioned are deprecated / no longer supported.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es

Comment: @Jxx Do you have any explanation on why run babel before uglify?

Answer (score 24):

There is no supporting ugilify(minify) tools for ES6 Syntax. 
you should be build gulp task after babel compile (es6 -> es5)

1.Install packages

`npm install gulp-babel babel-preset-es2015`

2.change your code as below.

```
    var gulp = require("gulp");
    var concat = require("gulp-concat");
    var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
    var babel  = require('gulp-babel');

    gulp.task("scripts", function() {
        return gulp.src(["./gulp-crash-test.js"])
    .pipe(babel({presets: ['es2015']}))
    .pipe(concat("gulp-crash-test.minjs"))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
         console.log(e);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./"))
    });
```

Comment: I don't know why people here I giving advices with babel, the question was clearly how to minify ecma6 code, and that question is still unanswered

Comment: Piping `.pipe(uglify({ compress: true })` into the above answer will result in minified ES2015 code.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [babel minify](https://github.com/babel/minify/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-minify) (previously Babili) a library based on babel to minify ES6 code without transpiling:

First install via npm:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-minify
```

Then in your gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var babel = require('gulp-babel')
gulp.task('default', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/app.js')
  .pipe(babel({presets: ['minify']}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

It uses babel as a parser, but there is no transpilation.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Babili requires node>=4.0.0

Comment: i prefer this method since im targeting ES6

Comment: Didn't work for me... the install doesn't appear to be the right one. Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-babel' - why are you installing babel-preset-minify and referring to it as gulp-babel? Did you try your own install before posting?

Comment: @johnblair Obviously you need to install gulp-babel since you are requiring, same goes for gulp. I added the install on the preset because that is not obvious from the code, babel loads it from the configuration

Comment: Ok. I gave up with Babel as i found lots of issues with version incompatibilites and i didn't actually need or want the transpiling - just the minification.. In the end I used gulp-uglifyes to minimise my ES6 js. Posting the code here in case anyone else finds it useful.   uglify = require("gulp-uglifyes")
// Minify the file
        .pipe(uglify({
            mangle: true,
            ecma: 6
        }))

Answer (score 3):

I tried babeli it kinda sucked. build time took me 40s. And I am not looking to transpile the code into es5 anyway

I prefer using uglify-es follow the descriptions
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify

My build times are now 10s. I have the patience to wait 10s.

This is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');
var htmlminifier = require('gulp-html-minifier');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var uglifyes = require('uglify-es');
var composer = require('gulp-uglify/composer');
var minifyes = composer(uglifyes, console);

.pipe(gulpif('*.js', minifyes()))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use for useref with angular and babel.

```
gulp.task('concat-js', ['your dependency task'],function(){
  return gulp.src('dev/dev_index/index.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', ngAnnotate())) // if you use angular
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js',babel({
        compact: false,
        presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}]]
     })))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify({ compress: false })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first 'babel' the .js file

```
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
gulp.task('babel-js', () =>
gulp.src('js/main.js')
 .pipe(babel({presets: ['env']}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('build/babel'))
);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel

than 'uglify' it

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'), pump = require('pump');
gulp.task('uglify-js', function (cb) {
   pump([
     gulp.src('build/babel/main.js'),
     uglify(),
     gulp.dest('build/js')
   ],
   cb
);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify

To be installed

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-babel babel-core babel-preset-env
npm install uglify-es -g
npm install pump
```