# GulpUglifyError - filter function jQuery

Tags: jquery, gulp, gulp-uglify

I have the following code but when I try to build it, I get this error:
events.js:174
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript

This is my code:

```
$('.wp-block-button__link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var array = window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(word => word.length > 0);
        window.location.href = href.trim('/') + '?brand=' + array[array.length - 1];
    });
```

This line is problematic:

```
            var array = window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(word => word.length > 0);
```

I think filter is the problem but i wonder if there's anything i can use instead of it?

Comment: You can always use a loop

Comment: can you please explain how? i'm new to this @php_nub_qq

Comment: I think it has something to do with the arrow (`=>`), try with `window.location.pathname.split('/').filter(function(word){return word.length > 0});`

Comment: Also this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179245/gulp-uglify-unable-to-handle-arrow-functions